# Rolling Disk Animation

Tags: graphics, manipulate

I am trying to create an animation in Mathematica of a rolling disk outside a disk of equal radius. The following coding is what I have tried but without the one circle staying in a fixed position I am having a hard time seeing what is going on.

```
Manipulate[
Show[{
  Graphics[{
      Circle[{0,0},1],
      Circle[{2 Cos[Theta],2 Sin[Theta]},1],
      {Blue,PointSize[0.012],Point[{Cos[Theta],Sin[Theta]}]},
      {Green, PointSize[0.012],Point[{2 Cos[Theta],2 Sin[Theta]}]},
      Line[{{2 Cos[Theta],2 Sin[Theta]},{Cos[Theta],Sin[Theta]}}]
     }]
  }]
,{Theta,0.0000001,2 Pi}
]
```

I also cannot figure out the how to make it trace the point that is rotating.

Comment: Use the `PlotRange` option to keep the stationary circle from moving around in the frame. In order to plot the path you should use `ParametricPlot` to plot the coordinate for the second circle over time. You can combine the `ParametricPlot` with your graphics using `Show`.

Comment: Stan Wagon's *Mathematica in Action* features an animation that involves rolling a (simulated) penny on another. If you can see a copy of that book, go do so.

Answer (score 4):

Is this something like what you want?

```
Manipulate[Show[
  Graphics[{
    Circle[{0, 0}, 1],
    Circle[{2 Cos[t], 2 Sin[t]}, 1], {Blue, PointSize[0.012], 
     Point[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}]}, {Green, PointSize[0.012], 
     Point[{2 Cos[t], 2 Sin[t]}]}, 
    Line[{{2 Cos[t], 
       2 Sin[t]}, {2 Cos[t], 2 Sin[t]} + {Cos[Pi + 2 t], Sin[Pi + 2 t]}}]
    }, PlotRange -> {{-3.1, 3.1}, {-3.1, 3.1}}],
  ParametricPlot[{2 Cos[t], 2 Sin[t]} + {Cos[Pi + 2 t], Sin[Pi + 2 t]},
    {t, 0, 2 Pi}]], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image: rolling]

You need to set a fixed `PlotRange` to stop the graphics from jumping around.  A `ParametricPlot` can be used to show the path it traces out, but you need to work out the formula yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an approach using [`ParametricPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html), where [`ListAnimate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListAnimate.html) permits smooth animation.

```
 testparaNew[α_] := Show[{
   ParametricPlot[
    {{Cos[θ], Sin[θ]},
     {2 Cos[α] + Cos[θ], 
      2 Sin[α] + Sin[θ]}},
    {θ, 0, 2 π},
    PlotRange -> 3,
    Axes -> False,
    Frame -> False
    ],
   ParametricPlot[
    {{2 Cos[α] + r Cos[2 α + π], 
      2 Sin[α] + r Sin[2 α + π]}},
    {r, 0, 1},
    PlotRange -> 3,
    Frame -> False,
    PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}
    ],
   ParametricPlot[
    {{2 Cos[β] + Cos[2 β + π], 
      2 Sin[β] + Sin[2 β + π]}},
    {β, 0, 2 π},
    PlotRange -> 3,
    Frame -> False,
    PlotStyle -> {Red, Thin}
    ]
   }]
list4 = Table[testparaNew[α], {α, 0, 2 π - π/60, π/60}]
ListAnimate[list4]
```

> [image]