# Animation stays blank during animation

Tags: plotting, animation

In attempting to answer [this question about animating a rolling disk](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/81126/rolling-disk-animation), I constructed a [`ParametricPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html) to [`Animate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Animate.html). The plot looks fine when not animated, yet while the animation runs the slider moves but there is no plot until the animation stops; after a short delay, the final state of the plot shows up.

How do I ensure the animation shows the elements of the plot?

```
 mypara[α_] := ParametricPlot[
   {
    {Cos[θ], Sin[θ]},
    {2 Cos[α] + Cos[θ], 
     2 Sin[α] + Sin[θ]}
   },
   {θ, 0, 2 π},
   {r, 1, 2},
   PlotRange -> 3,
   Frame -> False
   ]
 Animate[
   mypara[α],
   {α, 0, 2 π, π/6},
   AnimationRepetitions -> 1
   ]
```

> [image]

Comment: Use `Block[{$PerformanceGoal}, mypara[\[Alpha]]]` p.s. there is `y0` definition missing.

Comment: Thanks @kuba - this solves the immediate problem: the plot is visible. Unfortunately, it doesn't run smoothly but instead jumps to discrete points in the animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is just to render the frames first and then use `ListAnimate`,
(BTW I set y0 to -0.1, since its definition is missing)

```
mypara[\[Alpha]_] := 
  ParametricPlot[{{Cos[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Theta]]}, 
  {2 Cos[\[Alpha]] + Cos[\[Theta]], 2 Sin[\[Alpha]] + Sin[\[Theta]]},
  {r, 0}}, 
  {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {r, 1, 2}, PlotRange -> 3, Frame -> False]

 list1 = Table[mypara[\[Alpha]], {\[Alpha], 0, 2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/6}]
 ListAnimate[list1, AnimationRepetitions -> 1]
```

Comment: Thank you @lalmei ; this did work once. Unfortunately, the statement `Table[myparaL[α], {α, 0, 2 π, π/16}]` now crashes my kernel every time if I try it with a higher number of snapshots in the `Table`, even after restarting Mathematica.

Comment: @zentient Most likely is due to the fact you are using Pi instead of its numerical value, change the integers to real values 2 ->2.0 16->16.0 etc.

Comment: Thanks again. Using real values does help slightly. Unfortunately, generating the `Table` of `ParametricPlot`s crashes regularly when generating only a slightly larger number of plots in the `Table`.